# Why I'm having a lot of errors: unresolved external symbols on visual studio? Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-errors, unresolved-external

These are the errors I'm getting:

- unresolved external symbol "unsigned char * gkey" (?gkey@@3PAEA)
- unresolved external symbol "unsigned char * gPasswordHash" (?gPasswordHash@@3PAEA)
- unresolved external symbol "int_coded sha256(char *,char*,unsigned long,unsigned char * const)" (?sha256@@YAHPAD0KQAE@Z) referenced in function _main
- unresolved external symbol "unsigned char gdebug1" (?gdebug1@@3EA)
- unresolved external symbol "unsigned char gdebug2" (?gdebug2@@3EA)
- unresolved external symbol "char * gInFileName" (?gInFileNAME@@3PADA)
- unresolved external symbol "char * gOutFileName" (?gOutFileName@@3PADA)
- unresolved external symbol "char * gKeyFileName" (?gKeyFileName@@3PADA)

This is the code I'm working on:

```
    #include "Header.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// code to encrypt the data as specified by the project assignment
int encryptData(char* data, int dataLength)
{
    int resulti = 0;

    gdebug1 = 0;                    // a couple of global variables that could be used for debugging
    gdebug2 = 0;                    // also can have a breakpoint in C code

    // You can not declare any local variables in C, but should use resulti to indicate any errors
    // Set up the stack frame and assign variables in assembly if you need to do so
    // access the parameters BEFORE setting up your own stack frame
    // Also, you cannot use a lot of global variables - work with registers

    __asm {
        // you will need to reference some of these global variables
        // (gptrPasswordHash or gPasswordHash), (gptrKey or gkey), gNumRounds

        // simple example that xors 2nd byte of data with 14th byte in the key file
        mov esi, gptrKey;                       // put the ADDRESS of gkey into esi (since *gptrKey = gkey)
        mov esi, gptrPasswordHash               // put ADDRESS of gPasswordHash into esi (since unsigned char *gptrPasswordHash = gPasswordHash)
        xor eax, eax
        mov al, byte ptr[esi]
        xor ecx, ecx
        mov cl, byte ptr[esi +1]
        add ax, cx

        xor ebx, ebx
        xor ecx, ecx
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi]                   // get first byte of password hash
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 1]
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 2]
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 3]
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 4]               // get 5th byte of password hash
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 5]

        mov ecx, dataLength
        mov edi, data

    LOOP1 :
        mov dl, byte ptr[edi + ebx]
        xor dl, byte ptr[esi + eax]
        mov byte ptr[edi + ebx], dl

        add ebx, 1
        cmp ebx, ecx
        mov ebx, 2
        ja EXIT_END
        jmp LOOP1

    EXIT_END :
        xor ebx, ebx

    EXIT :
        mov resulti, ebx
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + ebx]             // get 3rd byte of password hash
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + ebx * 2]         // get 5th byte of password hash

//      mov ax, word ptr[esi + ebx * 2]         // gets 5th and 6th bytes of password hash ( gPasswordHash[4] and gPasswordHash[5] ) into ax
//      mov eax, dword ptr[esi + ebx * 2]       // gets 4 bytes, as in:  unsigned int X = *( (unsigned int*) &gPasswordHash[4] );

//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey]
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + 1]
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + ebx]            // get's 3rd byte of gkey[] data
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + ebx + 1]
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + ebx + 2]
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + ebx + 3]

//      mov al, byte ptr[gptrKey + ebx]         // THIS IS INCORRECT - will add the address of the gptrKey global variable (NOT the value that gptrKey holds)

//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 0xd];            // access 14th byte in gkey[]: 0, 1, 2 ... d is the 14th byte
                                                // Put ADDRESS of first data element into edi

//      xor byte ptr[edi + 1], al               // Exclusive-or the 2nd byte of data with the 14th element of the keyfile
                                                // NOTE: Keyfile[14] = 0x21, that value changes the case of a letter and flips the LSB
                                                // Capital "B" = 0x42 becomes lowercase "c" since 0x42 xor 0x21 = 0x63
    }

    return resulti;
} // encryptData

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// code to encrypt the data as specified by the project assignment
int decryptData(char* data, int dataLength)
{
    int resulti = 0;

    gdebug1 = 0;                    // a couple of global variables that could be used for debugging
    gdebug2 = 0;                    // also can have a breakpoint in C code

    // You can not declare any local variables in C, but should use resulti to indicate any errors
    // Set up the stack frame and assign variables in assembly if you need to do so
    // access the parameters BEFORE setting up your own stack frame
    // Also, you cannot use a lot of global variables - work with registers

    __asm {
        // you will need to reference some of these global variables
        // (gptrPasswordHash or gPasswordHash), (gptrKey or gkey), gNumRounds

        // simple example that xors 2nd byte of data with 14th byte in the key file
        mov esi, gptrKey;                       // put the ADDRESS of gkey into esi (since *gptrKey = gkey)
        mov esi, gptrPasswordHash               // put ADDRESS of gPasswordHash into esi (since unsigned char *gptrPasswordHash = gPasswordHash)

        xor eax, eax
        mov cl, byte ptr[esi + 1]
        add ax, cx

        xor ebx, ebx
        xor ecx, ecx
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi]                   // get first byte of password hash
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 1]
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 2]
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 3]
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 4]               // get 5th byte of password hash
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 5]

//      mov ebx, 2
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + ebx]             // get 3rd byte of password hash
//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + ebx * 2]         // get 5th byte of password hash

//      mov ax, word ptr[esi + ebx * 2]         // gets 5th and 6th bytes of password hash ( gPasswordHash[4] and gPasswordHash[5] ) into ax
//      mov eax, dword ptr[esi + ebx * 2]       // gets 4 bytes, as in:  unsigned int X = *( (unsigned int*) &gPasswordHash[4] );

        mov ecx, dataLength
        mov edi, data

     LOOP1 :
        mov dl, byte ptr[edi + ebx]
        xor dl, byte ptr[esi + eax]
        mov byte ptr[edi + ebx], dl

        add ebx, 1
        cmp ebx, ecx
        ja EXIT_END
        jmp LOOP1

    EXIT_END :
        xor ebx, ebx

    EXIT :
        mov resulti, ebx
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey]
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + 1]
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + ebx]            // get's 3rd byte of gkey[] data
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + ebx + 1]
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + ebx + 2]
//      mov al, byte ptr[gkey + ebx + 3]

//      mov al, byte ptr[gptrKey + ebx]         // THIS IS INCORRECT - will add the address of the gptrKey global variable (NOT the value that gptrKey holds)

//      mov al, byte ptr[esi + 0xd];            // access 14th byte in gkey[]: 0, 1, 2 ... d is the 14th byte
//      mov edi, data                           // Put ADDRESS of first data element into edi
//      xor byte ptr[edi + 1], al               // Exclusive-or the 2nd byte of data with the 14th element of the keyfile
                                                // NOTE: Keyfile[14] = 0x21, that value changes the case of a letter and flips the LSB
                                                // Capital "B" = 0x42 becomes lowercase "c" since 0x42 xor 0x21 = 0x63
//      xor esi, esi
    }

    return resulti;

} // decryptData

FILE* openInputFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* fptr;

    // FILE* fopen(const char* file_name, const char* mode_of_operation);
    fptr = fopen("AfterDebugging.jpg", "rb");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\nError - Could not open input file %s!\n\n", filename);
        exit(-1);
    }
    return fptr;
} // openInputFile


FILE* openOutputFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* fptr;

    fptr = fopen("AfterDebugging.jpg", "wb+");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\nError - Could not open output file %s!\n\n", filename);
        exit(-1);
    }
    return fptr;
} // openOutputFile


void usage(char* argv[])    //   cryptor.exe -e -i <input file> �k <keyfile> -p <password> [�r <#rounds>]
{
    printf("\n\nUsage:\n\n");
    printf("%s -<e=encrypt or d=decrypt> -i <message_filename> -k <keyfile> -p <password> [-r <#rounds>]\n\n", argv[0]);
    printf("-e              :encrypt the specified file\n");
    printf("-d              :decrypt the specified file\n");
    printf("-i filename     :the name of the file to encrypt or decrypt\n");
    printf("-p password     :the password to be used for encryption [default='password']\n");
    printf("-r <#rounds>    :number of encryption rounds (1 - 3)  [default = 1]\n");
    printf("-o filename     :name of the output file [default='encrypted.txt' or 'decrypted.txt'\n\n");
    exit(0);
} // usage

void parseCommandLine(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int cnt;
    char ch;
    bool i_flag, o_flag, k_flag, p_flag, error_flag;

    i_flag = k_flag = false;                // these must be true in order to exit this function
    error_flag = p_flag = o_flag = false;       // these will generate different actions

    cnt = 1;    // skip program name
    while (cnt < argc)
    {
        ch = *argv[cnt];
        if (ch != '-')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "All options must be preceeded by a dash '-'\n\n");
            usage(argv);
        }

        ch = *(argv[cnt] + 1);
        if (0)
        {
        }

        else if (ch == 'e' || ch == 'E')
        {
            if (gOp != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specified encrypt or decrypt.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            gOp = 1;    // encrypt
        }

        else if (ch == 'd' || ch == 'D')
        {
            if (gOp != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specified encrypt or decrypt.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            gOp = 2;    // decrypt
        }

        else if (ch == 'i' || ch == 'I')
        {
            if (i_flag == true)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed an input file.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            i_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must specify a filename after '-i'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            strncpy(gInFileName, argv[cnt], 256);
        }

        else if (ch == 'o' || ch == 'O')
        {
            if (o_flag == true)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed an output file.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            o_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must specify a filename after '-o'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            strncpy(gOutFileName, argv[cnt], 256);
        }

        else if (ch == 'k' || ch == 'K')
        {
            if (k_flag == true)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed a key file.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            k_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must specify a filename after '-k'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            strncpy(gKeyFileName, argv[cnt], 256);
        }

        else if (ch == 'p' || ch == 'P')
        {
            if (p_flag == true)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Already specifed a password.\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            p_flag = true;
            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must enter a password after '-p'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            strncpy(gPassword, argv[cnt], 256);
        }

        else if (ch == 'r' || ch == 'R')
        {
            int x;

            cnt++;
            if (cnt >= argc)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error! Must enter number between 1 and 3 after '-r'\n\n");
                usage(argv);
            }
            x = atoi(argv[cnt]);
            if (x < 1 || x > 3)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Warning! Entered bad value for number of rounds. Setting it to one.\n\n");
                x = 1;
            }
            gNumRounds = x;
        }

        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! Illegal option in argument. %s\n\n", argv[cnt]);
            usage(argv);
        }

        cnt++;
    } // end while

    if (gOp == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Encrypt or Decrypt must be specified.\n\n)");
        error_flag = true;
    }

    if (i_flag == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! No input file specified.\n\n");
        error_flag = true;
    }

    if (k_flag == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! No key file specified.\n\n");
        error_flag = true;
    }

    if (p_flag == false)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning! Using default 'password'.\n\n");
    }

    if (error_flag)
    {
        usage(argv);
    }
    return;
} // parseCommandLine

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int length, resulti;

    // parse command line parameters
    parseCommandLine(argc, argv);       // sets global variables, checks input options for errors

    // open the input and output files
    gfptrIn = openInputFile(gInFileName);
    gfptrKey = openInputFile(gKeyFileName);
    gfptrOut = openOutputFile(gOutFileName);

    length = (size_t)strlen(gPassword);

    resulti = sha256(NULL, gPassword, length, gPasswordHash);       // get sha-256 hash of password
    if (resulti != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Password not hashed correctly.\n\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    length = fread(gkey, 1, 65537, gfptrKey);
    if (length != 65537)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Length of key file is not at least 65537.\n\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fclose(gfptrKey);
    gfptrKey = NULL;

    if (gOp == 1)   // encrypt
    {
        encryptFile(gfptrIn, gfptrOut);
    }
    else
    {
        decryptFile(gfptrIn, gfptrOut);
    }

    fclose(gfptrIn);
    fclose(gfptrOut);

} // main
```

and this is the header file:

```
#pragma once
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

// Main.h
//
// This file is the main header file for the CS3843 Encrypt/Decrypt project
//

// Include Files
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>

// Defines
// #define TEST_CODE

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#define CRYPTO_ORDER "ABCDE\0"
#define var_Index -4
#define var_HopCnt -8
#define var_RoundNum -12
#define var_DataLength -16


#define FALL_2017       201708
#define SPRING_2018     201801
#define SUMMER_2018     201806
#define FALL_2018       201808

#define CURRENT_SEMESTER FALL_2018

// Structures


// Prototypes
int sha256(char* fileName, char* dataBuffer, DWORD dataLength, unsigned char sha256sum[32]);
void encryptData_01(char* data, int length);
void decryptData_01(char* data, int length);
void encryptData_02(char* data, int length);
void decryptData_02(char* data, int length);
int encryptData_03(char* data, int length);
int decryptData_03(char* data, int length);
int encryptData_Final(char* data, int length);
int decryptData_Final(char* data, int length);

// Global Variable Extern Declarations
extern unsigned char gkey[65537];
extern unsigned char* gptrKey = gkey;
extern char gPassword[256] = "SECRET";
extern unsigned char gPasswordHash[32];
extern unsigned char* gptrPasswordHash = gPasswordHash;
extern char gCRYPTO_ORDER[8];
extern unsigned char gdebug1, gdebug2;

extern FILE* gfptrIn = NULL;
extern FILE* gfptrOut = NULL;
extern FILE* gfptrKey = NULL;
extern char gInFileName[256];
extern char gOutFileName[256];
extern char gKeyFileName[256];
extern int gOp = 0;         // 1 = encrypt, 2 = decrypt
extern int gNumRounds = 1;

extern unsigned char gEncodeTable[256];
extern unsigned char gDecodeTable[256];
```

Comment: Do you include the file containing the definitions in your linker command? The header only provides declarations. It does not provide the implementation of the functions and variables.

Comment: Seems that some variables aren't defined in the snippets your provided. Where do you define e.g. `gdebug1` and `gdebug2`? Are you linking your code with the file containing those definitions?

Comment: @Gerhardh No? I don't know what is linker command?

Comment: No. A function prototype does not contain any code. An extern declaration of a variable does not reserve any storage for that. Exception: Variables that are initialized. But you should never do that in a header as you get a defitinion in each C file including that header causing multiple definition errors.

Comment: You might take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Comment: Actually, I can't really tell you the solution. I don't know where the definitions of your variables and functions are. Are they in some library or in some other C file? Is that your code? Anyhow, you need to include that file into your linker process. I don't use Visual Studio. Maybe you just need to add a C file to the project and it will be added to the linker. In addition you should look up some C tutorial about declaration vs definition. Also on SO you might find a few questions and answers about that.